# Platform to visualize system infrastructure

Tags: architecture, drawing, visualization, system

What's the best `web-based` platform to visualize system architecture ?

For example, I want to draw/visualize how client hits `http` server, then `http` server hits `database` server and so on.

What kind of options do we have today ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use [this](https://app.diagrams.net/) website (known as draw.io) for a couple of years to build architecture diagrams/flows. There are multiple reasons I like this platform:

- It's free (at least for most of the diagrams you may need to create)
- It has a desktop version, but the online version works really well (haven't noticed any significant lag)
- The number and type of the components/objects you can use is enough for most use-cases (that I had, at least)
- The objects can be arranged in a very granular way, by using the arrow keys (if the sticky connections feature doesn't help)
- You can export the diagram in different formats, you can even embed it in HTML if you need to.

Although this platform allows you to build sequence diagrams, a better option for this would be [PlantUML](https://plantuml.com/). It's really straight forward to learn the language. [Here](https://plantuml.com/sequence-diagram) is an example on how to build a sequence diagram.

Comment: I found `Gliffy`, but your suggestions seems very interesting for me.

This is answer.
Thanks !

Comment: No worries! `Gliffy` is a good option too, I worked with it a few times, but I felt that draw.io fits better on my use-cases. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean the interaction between client <> server <> database? If that is the case, a sequence diagram is the best UML diagram for you. And you may want to try https://ZenUML.com. (disclaimer: I created ZenUML because I love sequence diagrams.)

Here is an examplpe:
[image]

Comment: Looks very interesting. I will check it.

Thanks !